# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'value,value' to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
update Quotation_T  
set DOID = CASE 
              WHEN DOID = '' THEN 19
              WHEN DOID LIKE '%10%' THEN DOID       
              WHEN DOID != '' THEN (DOID + ',' + '20')
           END
```

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '19,20' to data type int

Comment: Most likely, `DOID` is a `nvarchar(n)` column - then it's obvious: your `CASE` expression **must return** the same datatype for all paths, and since the first `WHEN` clause returns an `INT`, all other paths also must return an `INT`, and if they don't, SQL Server will convert their return values to `INT` which causes the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `DOID` is a `nvarchar(n)` column - then it's obvious: your `CASE` expression **must return** the same datatype for all paths, and since the first `WHEN` clause returns an `INT`, all other paths also must return an `INT`, and if they don't, SQL Server will convert their return values to `INT` which causes the exception.

Also: since you're **updating** the `DOID` column, you should use its native data type - so your first `WHEN` clause should **return** a `nvarchar(n)` instead of an `INT`.

Try this code instead:

```
UPDATE Quotation_T  
SET DOID = CASE 
              WHEN DOID = '' THEN CAST(19 AS NVARCHAR(20))
              WHEN DOID LIKE '%10%' THEN DOID       
              WHEN DOID != '' THEN (DOID + N',20')
           END
```

Now, all `WHEN` clauses properly return the datatype that `DOID` being updated expects, and no implicit conversions are necessary.

Comment: it's working.i need one more help.
select distinct A.Item_Code,(B.Description + '-' + B.Product_Code + '(' + D.Brand_Name+ ')') as Description,A.Quantity,B.UOM,A.Rate,A.DOID,C.Doc_No,B.Tax_Percentage as Tax,B.Tax_Percentage as Tax1,F.QuotationID 
FROM DO_T A INNER JOIN inv_Item_Master B ON A.Item_Code=B.Item_Code INNER JOIN DO C ON A.DOID=C.DOID inner join Inv_Brand D on  D.Brand_ID = B.Brand_ID INNER JOIN Quotation_T F ON F.DOID = A.DOID WHERE A.DOID like '%'+@DOID+'%' and a.BR_Code=@brcode
END.got same error:Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '22,23' to data type int.

Comment: @neethamathew: post a new question for this

Comment: Why would you cast `19` rather than use `N'19'`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: didn't know if that `19` was actually a value from a column or variable - but I agree - using `N'19'` as a string literal would be just as good

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend writing the code as:

```
update Quotation_T  
    set DOID = (case when doid = '' then '19'
                     else (DOID + ',20')
                end)
    where doid not like '%10%' or doid is null;
```

This does not even attempt to update the rows that do not need to be updated.

I would also make the observation that you seem to be storing comma-delimited strings in a single column.  If so, I would strongly urge you to reconsider your data model, and use a separate junction table instead.  SQL is not really designed to store lists of things in strings.  This (and other questions you ask) show that mixing types and storing multiple values in a column just create unnecessary problems.